# jQuery with ASP.NET MVC 3 books/tutorials?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery, asp.net-ajax

Are there any books / tutorials on jQuery with ASP.NET MVC 3?  I need to learn how to use ajax links and how to submit ajax forms ect.  If there aren't any books / tutorials on MVC 3 yet MVC 2 wil also suffice.

P.S I do know how to do basic stuff with the MS AJAX Toolkit that comes with MVC

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best 2 books are:

Pro ASP.NET MVC 2:  [http://www.amazon.com/ASP-NET-Framework-Second-Experts-Voice/dp/1430228865/ref=pd_sim_b_1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430228865)

jQuery in Action:  [http://www.amazon.com/jQuery-Action-Bear-Bibeault/dp/1933988355](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988355)

There is the MVC 3 version of Pro ASP.NET MVC:  [http://www.amazon.com/Pro-ASP-NET-MVC-Framework-Third/dp/1430234040/ref=dp_ob_title_bk](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430234040)

There is a basic MVC 3 tutorial on the ASP.NET site:  http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript

Also a great video tutorial here, http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=aspdotnet-mvc3-intro, there is a whole 47m chapter dedicated to AJAX and Javascript (including jQuery).

Answer (score 3):

The book mentioned previously is available now from `Apress` under their alpha books program, I've got it and recommend it - though what I've read so far `jQuery` code is sparse, mostly just leveraging the library's built in support for Ajax and validation.

They do refer readers to the `jQuery` site and to `Stack Overflow` for more info :-)

Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework from Apress.com

Here's a couple more resources that are free (also see the site [learningjquery.com](http://www.learningjquery.com) if new to `jQuery`):

- [ASP-NET-MVC-and-jQuery-Part-1-Getting-Started](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/74338/ASP-NET-MVC-and-jQuery-Part-1-Getting-Started.aspx)
- [Come-in-as-jQuery-zero-go-out-as-jQuery-hero](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Web-Camp-Belgium-2011/Web-Camps-Belgium-Come-in-as-jQuery-zero-go-out-as-jQuery-hero)

Bruce.